# How to use math expression in the result of a case expression in both Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2012

I wanted to use a math expression in result of the case statement.
For Eg,

```
select T1.C1, T1.C2, T1.C3,
case 
when T1.C1 = T1.C2 <or any condition for that sake>
then (T1.C3 + 1) --> I want to achieve this
when T1.C1 <> T1.C2
then (T1.C3 + 2)
when T1.C1<T1.C2
then 0 --> just display 0
end as C4 from Table T1;
```

I have tried a similar query as mentioned in the example in Oracle SQL. I have not got any errors while execution but the result is not displayed. Only the result of displaying 0 is obtained, other results are not displayed

Comment: Try `AS C4` instead of `as T1.C4`?

Comment: OK, I guess the issue is with my condition expression which I am using. Here the T1.C1 and T1.C2 are strings. I am not sure if I can directly use '=' to compare 2 columns which has string values.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, though I'm unfamiliar with any differences in the implementation of `CASE` expressions in Oracle (or if maybe you are in some kind of try/catch logic that is hiding the error from you). I do know that your third condition could never be reached - if the third condition is true, the second condition must also be true.

Comment: I have just given the conditions as name sake. those are not the exact conditions. what I am worried about is the result math expression which is not getting dispalyed. :(

Comment: Well, why are you saying `<string> + 1`? I think it's going to be very hard for us to help you troubleshoot code that's not even your real code, not understanding where you're running this, etc. etc. I think that "result is not displayed" is a symptom of something other than the expression inside `CASE`. Does the query return results *without* the `CASE`?

Comment: Apologies for I could not give the entire query as this is just a part of a logic applied in my query. This query runs when executed without the case statement. With case statement also it is executed but the C4 column is not updated as expected. Also I have changed the expression now. The condition and the expression doesnt matter exactly only is that I would want to know if we can use the math expression like this or not. Extremely sorry for not being able to explain the entire query.

Comment: The CASE statement ought to work, even if you're comparing strings. So I think you need to post some sample data which reproduces the problem. Oh, and your actual code or some redaction of it which demonstrates the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure if I can directly use '=' to compare 2 columns which has string values.

Assuming that you are storing numbers in a string (`VARCHAR`) field and adding one to them makes sense (even if it does leave us questioning the design decision of using strings) then:

**Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( c1 VARCHAR(1), c2 VARCHAR(1), c3 VARCHAR(1) );
INSERT INTO t1 ( c1, c2, c3 ) VALUES( '1', '1', '1' );
INSERT INTO t1 ( c1, c2, c3 ) VALUES( '1', '2', '1' );
INSERT INTO t1 ( c1, c2, c3 ) VALUES( '1', NULL, '1' );
```

**Query**:

Your third condition `T1.C1<T1.C2` will never be reached as it is matched by the second condition `T1.C1 <> T1.C2`. If, instead, it is replaced by an `ELSE` condition then this will be matched when one-or-other value is `NULL` and both `T1.C1 = T1.C2` and `T1.C1 <> T1.C2` will be false. (Also, you don't need the table aliases everywhere as you are only using a single table; so in the interest of simplicity and readability they've been removed)

```
select C1,
       C2,
       C3,
       case 
       when C1 =  C2 then C1 + 1
       when C1 <> C2 then C2 + 1
                     ELSE 0
       end as C4
from   T1;
```

**Oracle 18c Output**:

```
C1 | C2   | C3 | C4
:- | :--- | :- | -:
1  | 1    | 1  |  2
1  | 2    | 1  |  3
1  | null | 1  |  0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a98b594a555a0f18955a74e7b1c8f411)*

**SQL Server 2017 Output**:

*(SQL Server 2012 was unavailabe on DB<>Fiddle when I wrote this)*

```
C1 | C2   | C3 | C4
:- | :--- | :- | -:
1  | 1    | 1  |  2
1  | 2    | 1  |  3
1  | null | 1  |  0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a98b594a555a0f18955a74e7b1c8f411)*

The outputs are identical and the appropriate case conditions are reached and you can use `=` and `<>` to compare string columns.